# Blazor InputSelect control doesn't seem to bind

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, blazor-server-side

I have a strange problem with a Blazor Server InputSelect control on an EditForm. When the component is displayed the InputSelect control doesn't have a default value, however depending upon the user's action elsewhere on the form, the control can update to refresh the options within the InputSelect control.

```
<InputSelect class="form-select" @bind-Value="_documentEventUpdateModel.DocumentStatusId">
    @foreach (var documentStatus in GetValidDocumentStatuses())
    {
        <option value=@documentStatus.Id>@documentStatus.Name</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
```

The method called in the foreach statement is:

```
private List<DocumentStatusDto> GetValidDocumentStatuses()
{
    return this.DocumentService.GetValidDocumentStatuses(
        _documentEventUpdateModel.UpdateUserId,
        (DocumentStatuses)this.DocumentSummaryModel.DocumentStatusId);
}
```

The DocumentStatusDto class, is defined as follows:

```
public sealed class DocumentStatusDto : IEntity
{
    public required int Id { get; init; }
    public required string Name { get; init; }
}
```

I also override the OnInitialized method within the component to set a few other properties within the bound model for other form items.

Using the browser's element inspector after the control has updated, I can see the options added to the control have the correct Id property, and the first option appears to be selected in the control, however if the user clicks the form submit button without changing the selected item, the bound value in the model behaves as if no option was selected, as it doesn't take on the Id of the item that appears to be selected, it instead has a value of zero.

Users are having to expand the control, change the selection, and then re-select the first entry as a work around.

I have other similar inputs on other forms that work in an identical way that don't have this problem. What might I be doing wrong that is causing this behaviour?

Comment: It seems like you need to set the value of `_documentEventUpdateModel.DocumentStatusId` to the desired default value, same as the one in the drop down list. Or you may want to have a null value, or "Select an Item" as a default value for the initial state of the dropdown. You are seeing the first thing in the list because it is ... well .. the first thing in the list. But probably you are only actually setting or updating this value on your model when the selection changes.

Comment: Thanks @topsail, on first load the integer DocumentStatusId has a value of 0, and the control is then prepopulated with a number of options, yet nothing is selected by default. However when the available options update following user interaction with other components on the InputForm, DocumentStatusId remains unchanged at 0, but the control appears to select the first item from the new list as the default. I was hoping to shy away from having a default 'placeholder' item in the list, but it could be a good solution.

Comment: The main thing (so far as I can tell) is to not conflate *"an option is selected"* with *"the bound value is updated"*. If there is a programmatic way you are setting the option, make sure the same code also updates the bound value on the model.